# Open source stun turn server which can do hole punch is there similar packages?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, voip, nat

Is there any open source stun/turn server which can do hole punch like numb for Ubuntu ?

> Numb is a STUN/TURN server.
>
> Description
>
> A STUN/TURN server is used for NAT traversal in VoIP. Whether you're
>   at home behind a common router, at work behind an enterprise firewall,
>   or traveling, chances are that you will be behind a NAT which must be
>   traversed before making calls.
>
> Our server, Numb, will help your SIP phone automatically punch holes
>   in the NAT. As a solution of last resort, it will simply act as a
>   relay between you and the person you're talking to when end-to-end
>   connectivity just isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

One Ugly issue in history of networking is this NAT.

> STUN and TURN are sub-parts of the broad ICE framework. STUN and TURN
>   do not know about ICE and those protocols are just cubicles in the
>   general ICE picture. When you are using ICE, you have to set all the
>   components (including STUN and TURN) to work together. This TURN
>   server has all means to set it up correctly in any environment. How to
>   set up your particular ICE framework I have no idea and that is not my
>   concern. If you will see that the TURN server is doing something
>   incorrectly, then you can report it here.

For Linux we got:

1) resiprocate-turn-server
- http://www.resiprocate.org/ReSIProcate_1.8_Release

- community is deadly, like nobody is there

Ubuntu above 12.04 you should get so that you can install it as:

```
$ apt-get install resiprocate-turn-server
$ reTurnServer /etc/reTurnServer.config  --LogLevel=INFO
INFO |.662 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | UdpServer.cxx:29 | UdpServer started.  Listening on 0.0.0.0:3478
INFO |.662 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TcpServer.cxx:26 | TcpServer started.  Listening on 0.0.0.0:3478
ERR |.663 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TlsServer.cxx:30 | Unable to load server cert chain file: server.pem, error=22(Invalid argument)
ERR |.663 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TlsServer.cxx:37 | Unable to load server private key file: server.pem, error=22(Invalid argument)
ERR |.663 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TlsServer.cxx:44 | Unable to load temporary Diffie-Hellman parameters file: dh512.pem, error=22(Invalid argument)
INFO |.663 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TlsServer.cxx:55 | TlsServer started.  Listening on 0.0.0.0:5349

DEBUG |.552 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TcpConnection.cxx:39 | TcpConnection started.
WARNING |.181 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | AsyncTcpSocketBase.cxx:181 | Receive buffer (2048) is not large enough to accomdate incoming framed data (27764) closing connection.
DEBUG |.181 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TcpConnection.cxx:27 | TcpConnection destroyed.
^CDEBUG |.023 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TlsConnection.cxx:32 | TlsConnection destroyed.
DEBUG |.024 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TcpConnection.cxx:27 | TcpConnection destroyed.
INFO |.024 | reTurnServer | RETURN | | TurnManager.cxx:36 | Turn Manager destroyed.
```

Fedora 19: (optional)

```
$ yum install resiprocate-turn-server
```

2) rfc5766-turn-server: (community is active, not dead) http://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/downloads/list

```
$ turnserver -u username:password
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [restund](http://creytiv.com/restund.html), a relatively young and very promising project.